# Location without internet connection

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, swift2

I want to get the location of the user when press a button, I found a way to do that with CLLocationManager, that code work perfectly until the device the device doesn't have network connection, the function func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) catch an error

> ((NSError?) error = domain: "kCLErrorDomain" - code: 2 {   _userInfo =
>   nil })

How can I get the device location without internet connection? here is the code I use

```
import CoreLocation

class SesionViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager =  CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error:" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
                print(pm!.coordinate.latitude)
            }else {
                print("Error with data")
            }

        })
    }
func startButtonPress(sender:UIButton!){
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I already found the solution, I just don't execute CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation... just catch the location with the locations var like this

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(manager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
}
```

Comment: What device were you testing on? Not all iOS devices have GPS hardware so some devices requires an Internet connection.

Comment: did you had those two string into your p.list, and also you should use the status method to actually know if you are fully granted access

Comment: yes, I already have those strings... the problem was I shouldn't have implemented the contact with apple

Comment: @rmaddy can you tell me which devices have GPS hardware and which are not?

Comment: @Himanth See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Answer (score 1):

from Apple doc about ClGeocoder

> The computer or device must have access to the network in order for
>   the geocoder object to return detailed placemark information

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error:" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
                print(pm!.coordinate.latitude)
            }else {
                print("Error with data")
            }

        })
```

will always report an error without an internet access. Your location data are still available (if your device has GPS unit)

Comment: yes, thank... the problem was I don't need to call CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation, that was my problem.